# How to set up a react + express app on ubuntu on a subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

i'm trying to deploy a react app with express on a ubuntu server but I don't think i'm making much headway. I was able to get the entire front end(react) side working, but I can't seem to connect the client to the backend. I made sure to update the "homepage" in the package.json file before building the react app that it'll built with the subdirectory as the root. I have react router dom set up where when I access the url "tools.domain.com/style/{styleNumber}" then it makes a request to the express route "/getStyle".However, I receive a 405 error when trying to make that request. I have express running on port 6000. I'm not too sure if it's something I need to adjust in my nginx default.config file or possibly something in react/express? I've read that it has something to do with nginx not being able to make post requests through static files. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the error I am receiving when trying to make a request to the express route/endpoint:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdECo.jpg

Here is my default config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www/home;
server_name tools.domain.com;

location / {
        root /var/www/home;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}

location /app1 {
        alias /var/www/app1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app1/index.html;
}

location ^~ /app2 {
        alias /var/www/app2;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app2/index.html;
}

location /getStyle/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:6000/;
}
```

}

Comment: i think you should proxy incoming requests to your express app, since express act, also, as an http server.

Comment: @itishermann Thank you for your reply. I forgot to include the reverse proxy location on the post, my apologies. Here's what I have set up for a reverse proxy.